# Erro na associação N:N sequelize / nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize-js

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com nodejs, typescript e sequelize. Tenho 4 tabelas `users`, `products`, `sales` e `salesProducts` e o relacionamento entre as tabelas sales e products com a tabela salesProducts é N:N

Quero fazer uma consulta na tabela `sales` onde consiga visualizar os produtos daquela compra e os dados de usuário que fez aquela compra também,
essa parte do usuário eu já consigo trazer na consulta, mas para trazer os produtos está aparecendo a mensagem de erro para mim: `"error": "products is not associated to sales!"`

estou fazendo a chamada através da camada de **service**, o arquivo é esse:

```
class SaleService {
  private Sales = Sales;
  private Users = Users;
  private Products = Products;

  public async getSales() {
    const sales =  await this.Sales.findAll(
      {
        include: [
          { model: this.Users, as: 'user_id', attributes: { exclude: ['password'] } },
          { model: this.Products, as: 'product', through: { attributes: [] } }, //caso essa linha seja ocultada consigo realizar a consulta, visualizando os dados da compra e dados de usuário
        ]
      }
    );
    return sales;
  }
export { SaleService }
```

nas **models** defini a tabela `salesProducts` assim:

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import db from './index.model';
import Products from './products.model';
import Sales from './sales.model';

class SalesProducts extends Model {
  declare saleId: number;
  declare productId: number;
  declare quantity: number;
}

SalesProducts.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  saleId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: { model: 'sales', key: 'id' },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    field: 'sale_id',
  },
  productId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: { model: 'products', key: 'id' },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    field: 'product_id',
  },
  quantity: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {
  underscored: true,
  sequelize: db,
  modelName: 'salesProducts',
  timestamps: false,
});

Products.belongsToMany(Sales, {
  as: 'sales',
  through: SalesProducts,
  foreignKey: 'productId',
  otherKey: 'saleId',
});

Sales.belongsToMany(Products, {
  as: 'products',
  through: SalesProducts,
  foreignKey: 'saleId',
  otherKey: 'productId',
});

export default SalesProducts;
```

também nas **models** defini a tabela `sales` assim:

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import db from './index.model';
import Users from './users.model';
import Products from './products.model';

class Sales extends Model {
  declare id: number;
  declare userId: string;
  declare sellerId: string;
  declare totalPrice: number;
  declare saleDate: Date;
  declare statusSale: string;
}

Sales.init({
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  userId: DataTypes.STRING,
  sellerId: DataTypes.STRING,
  totalPrice: { type: DataTypes.DECIMAL, allowNull: false },
  saleDate: { type: DataTypes.DATE, defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW },
  statusSale: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
}, {
  underscored: true,
  sequelize: db,
  modelName: 'sales',
  timestamps: false,
});

// configs do relacionamento entre as tabelas Users e Sales
Users.hasMany(Products, {
  foreignKey: 'id',
  as: 'saleId'
})

Sales.belongsTo(Users, {
  foreignKey: 'userId',
  as: 'user_id'
})

export default Sales;
```

e também nas **models** defini a tabela `products` assim:

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import db from './index.model';

class Products extends Model {
  declare id: number;
  declare name: string;
  declare type: string;
  declare price: number;
  declare quantity: number;
  declare url_image: string;
}

Products.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  type: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  price: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
  quantity: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
  url_image: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
}, {
  underscored: true,
  sequelize: db,
  modelName: 'products',
  timestamps: false,
});

export default Products;
```

Pelo que pesquisei achei que era necessário somente usar o código abaixo na tabela de ligação

```
Products.belongsToMany(Sales, {
      as: 'sale',
      through: SalesProducts,
      foreignKey: 'productId',
      otherKey: 'saleId',
    });
    
    Sales.belongsToMany(Products, {
      as: 'products',
      through: SalesProducts,
      foreignKey: 'saleId',
      otherKey: 'productId',
    });
```

Como resolver esse problema de associação entre as tabelas products e sales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você notar as models `products` e `sales` não se relacionam por isso o erro.

Nas pesquisa você mesmo postou a resposta e acabou não notando

Basicamente você deve adicionar na model `products` esse relacionamento

```
Products.belongsToMany(Sales, {
  as: 'sales',
  through: SalesProducts,
  foreignKey: 'productId',
  otherKey: 'saleId',
});
```

e na model `sales` adicionar o outro relacionamento

```
Sales.belongsToMany(Products, {
  as: 'products',
  through: SalesProducts,
  foreignKey: 'saleId',
  otherKey: 'productId',
});
```

Comment: perfeito, não pensava que havia diferença entre fazer essas associações na tabela de ligação `salesProducts` ou usar as tabelas individualmente `sales` e `products`